# "Ridden" and "Riddled"

Tags: expressions, eggcorn

I am familiar with the "-ridden" construction, *e.g.* "anxiety-ridden". I also know that "riddled with X" is possible. I recently saw the combination "ridden with X", which sounds off to me, but I'm not sure whether my intuition is a reliable guide here. Does "ridden with X" make sense, or is it an eggcorn?

Comment: Does anxiety "ride" you, or does it "riddle" you. Both make sense. I don't know which came first, and which is the eggcorn.

Comment: @PeterShor Shouldn't it be "ridden by" rather than "ridden with", though?

Comment: It should definitely be "ridden by anxiety", and not "ridden with anxiety". Maybe somebody misconstrued "anxiety-ridden" to mean "ridden with anxiety". I don't think that counts as an eggcorn, because it's incorrect back-formation, and not a misheard pronunciation. You can google and find "anxiety-riddled" as well; that's an eggcorn.

Comment: @PeterShor - thanks, that's what I wanted to know. If you'll enter that as an answer I'll approve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be "ridden *by* anxiety", and not "ridden *with* anxiety". Maybe somebody misconstrued "anxiety-ridden" to mean "ridden with anxiety". I don't think that counts as an eggcorn, because it's incorrect back-formation, and not a misheard pronunciation.

You can google and find "anxiety-riddled" as well; that's an eggcorn. The "adjective-ridden" formation dates back to at least 1812 (here is ["fear-ridden"](http://books.google.com/books?id=0QwUAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA372&dq=fear-ridden&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ys6IUqbrFMf_4APlq4DYBg&ved=0CDQQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=fear-ridden&f=false) from Google books) and "adjective-riddled" only appears much later.

Comment: I don't think *-riddled* is an eggcorn. *Worm-riddled* (so full of holes it resembles a riddle or sieve) is both venerable and purely descriptive; what is wrong with *anxiety-riddled* as a metaphor?

Comment: I would say that "worm-riddled" is not an eggcorn, but "guilt-riddled" is.